# What is the difference between asymmetric and depthwise separable convolution?

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, comparison, convolution

I have recently discovered [asymmetric convolution layers](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.00567.pdf) in deep learning architectures, a concept which seems very similar to [depthwise separable convolutions](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.02357.pdf).

Are they really the same concept with different names? If not, where is the difference? To make it concrete, what would each one look like if applied to a 128x128 image with 3 input channels (say R,G,B) and 8 output channels?

NB: I cross-posted this from stackoverflow, since this kind of theoretical question is maybe better suited here. Hoping it is OK...

Comment: Hi and welcome to this community! This is the type of question that is suited for this website and **not** for Stack Overflow, which is dedicated to programming issues. So, I would delete the question from SO, unless you received a good answer there. Btw, it might be useful to link to that SO question.

Comment: You're right: I just deleted the SO question (which got no answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not the same thing.

asymmetric convolutions work by taking the x and y axes of the image separately. For example performing a convolution with an $(n \times 1)$ kernel before one with a $(1 \times n)$ kernel.

On the other-hand depth-wise separable convolutions separate the spatial and channel components of a 2D convolution. It will first perform the $(n \times n)$ convolution on each channel separately (full kernel shape will be $(n \times n \times 1)$ rather than $(n \times n \times k)$ where $k$ is the number of channels in the previous layer) before doing a $(1 \times 1)$ convolution to learn a relationship between the channels (full kernel size for that being $(1 \times 1 \times k)$)

Comment: Thanks, I think it's already clearer now. Just two extra questions: 1. How does the number of channels (input & output) play a role in the asymmetric convolution? 2. For the depthwise separable convolution, is a  $(1 \times 1 \times k)$ convolution just a linear combination of the channels (after the previous $(n \times n \times 1)$ convolution)?

Comment: 1) so the kernels are $(1\times n \times k)$ for each of the first one, and the $(n \times 1 \times m)$ where $m$ is the number of $1\ times n$ filters you used. The number of the second filter is the number of output channels thatll exist. (Generally used where $k=m$). 2) Yes.